# Cancelling NSURLConnection when leaving a view

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection

Do I need to cancel the opened connections (`NSURLConnection`) when I leave the view?
I'd do that in `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear` but I don't know whether I actually need to do that.

Comment: either one should not be a matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using ARC, there's a good chance your NSURLConnection objects (assuming they are instance variables or that you're holding onto them in memory somehow) will get magically released when the view controller goes away.

But to be sure, and to be nice, you should cancel the open connections.  Doing the NSURLConnection object ["`cancel`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLConnection/cancel) in either "`viewWillDisappear`" or "`viewDidDisappear`" should work well.

Comment: Yes, I'm using ARC. I'm allocating those objects in my XYZViewController as instance variables so I think that as soon as the view controller is released, those objects (NSURLConnections) are also released. But well, I'll cancel them anyway, just to be sure. Thanks. :)